# Como retornar uma tabela a partir do xml no sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml

Meu xml é parecido com isso:

```
<Operacao Id="1">
  <Contatos>
    <Contato Id="2013">
      <Emails>
        <Email Id="40"/>
        <Email Id="41"/>
      </Emails>
    </Contato>
    <Contato Id="2014">
      <Emails>
        <Email Id="44"/>
        <Email Id="45"/>
        <Email Id="47"/>
      </Emails>
    </Contato>
  </Contatos>
</Operacao>'
```

e gostaria de obter um retorno assim:

```
1   2013    40
1   2013    41
1   2014    44
1   2014    45
1   2014    47
```

essa query abaixo só me retorna a primeira linha:

```
select 
    c.value('(@Id)[1]','int') as [Operaca.Id],
    c.value('(Contatos/Contato/@Id)[1]','int') as [Contato.Id],
    c.value('(Contatos/Contato/Emails/Email/@Id)[1]','int') as [Email.Id]
from @xml.nodes('/Operacao') as t(c)
```

Como eu faço pra retornar as 5 linhas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode fazer da seguinte forma.:

```
DECLARE @xml as xml
SET @xml = '<Operacao Id="1">
  <Contatos>
    <Contato Id="2013">
      <Emails>
        <Email Id="40"/>
        <Email Id="41"/>
      </Emails>
    </Contato>
    <Contato Id="2014">
      <Emails>
        <Email Id="44"/>
        <Email Id="45"/>
        <Email Id="47"/>
      </Emails>
    </Contato>
  </Contatos>
</Operacao>';   

SELECT
    c.value('(../../../../@Id)[1]','int') as [OperacaId],
    c.value('(../../@Id)[1]','int') as [ContatoId],
    c.value('(@Id)[1]','int') as [EmailId]
FROM @xml.nodes('/Operacao/Contatos/Contato/Emails/Email') as t(c)
```

Comment: pootz! era o que eu precisava! obrigado!